# Constrained Local Model (CLM) – How can I compute the response map

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I try to implement a **facial feature detector with a CLM** following the paper of **Cootes et. al.**  **('Feature Detection and Tracking with Constrained Local Models' and 'Automatic feature localization with constrained local models').**

The training of the model worked out well and I got the expected results. Now I'm stuck with the building of the response image. According to the paper I have to calculate the normalized correlation response of every template patch with the underlying image around his current position ( I used the `normxcorr2` function from matlab).

I did this. But the result doesn't look like the pictures in the papers. And the Nelder-Meade optimization doesn't converge either.

Did I missed something? Has anyone implemented this algorithm yet and could anyone give me some hints? Is the `normxcorr2` function a bad choice?

Thanks!